# Handle model dependencies in Laravel Repository Pattern

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, repository-pattern

I'm discovering the Repository Pattern for my Laravel project but I have to say that I'm a bit lost once a model has several dependencies and the examples on the web are always basic and don't answer the question for more complex use cases.

Let's imagine a user on my app. He can have badges, he has different things on the app that will be slightly modified when he first performs the action (when he first sees the comments, I tell him once the different things he can do, etc), he has several "counters" to record the number of comments he made, the number of friends he invited, without having to count each entry each time.

My database looks like this:

users table:

```
id
pseudo
name
password
...
```

badges table:

```
user_id
badge1_xxxxxx
badge2_xxxxxx
...
```

I have a very limited number of badges so I decided to create a column for each of them and as soon as a user wins a badge, I get his entry (in OneToOne relationship) and I indicate that the badge in question has been won.

onboarding table:

```
user_id
seen_comments (boolean)
seen_results (boolean)
...
```

As you can see, I store each action I'd like the user to do in different columns and as soon as he has done one and I've been able to modify my app accordingly (by showing him an arrow, etc), I put the column in question to `true`.

user_counters table:

```
user_id
count_comments
count_invited_friends
...
```

I don't consider a user to be a user if he doesn't have an entry in each of the tables (I could have done everything in one table but the users table seemed to me to become huge). The only relationship used is OneToOne between the user and the table in question.

Should I do this ?

```
class UserRepository {

public function register($data) {
    // Create the user
    $user = User::create($data);
    
    // Create all its dependencies which are required if I want to consider the user as fully registered in my DB
    $user->badges()->create();
    $user->onboarding()->create();
    $user->counter()->create();
    
    // Return the user
    return $user;
}
```

}

Or should I create a Repository for each of these elements and create the entire user in a `UserService` ?

How far should I separate things and when does it become overkill?

Is there something that I don't understand in concept of Repository ? If so, could you give me some links that you found useful because I feel like I ran out of ideas for search keywords.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd need a repository for every model you have. The user repository will have the badges onboarding and counter repositories as dependencies in that case

Comment: This is what I thought I was doing at first and it seemed logical but then I saw on several articles that injecting Repositories into another Repository was a bad practice and that it was better to put everything in a Service. Nevertheless, in this case, it seems illogical to me to use a Service because it would mean that my `create` method in my UserRepository would be completely linked to the `register` method of the UserService.

Comment: Yes normally you wouldn't have a repository being coupled with other repositories because the repository is meant to be the OOP "representative" of a single table only. However if it doesn't make sense and it will never make sense to uncouple the user table with the badges, onboarding and counter tables then I would argue that coupling the repository with the corresponding repositories is just reflecting the underlying data coupling. This being said, a service would be playing safe in case you do want to uncouple things in future

Comment: Ok, you have a point about using the UserService and decoupling and to be honest, it has totally unlocked me about when to use a Repository or Service. Thank you! But now, if I create a `BadgeRepository` with a `create($user)` method inside of it, should I continue to use relationships and write `$user->badges()->create()` or give up relationships and use `Badge::create(['user_id' => $user->id])` ? The question may sound silly but with Eloquent, I have trouble understanding when to use and when not to use relationships inside of Repository.

Comment: One thing to ask yourself. How likely am I to rewrite this application in something other than laravel? If the answer is "Not likely" don't give up the things that make laravel great for the "notion" of good architecture.

Comment: For now, I haven't planned to rewrite my application with another technology but what do you mean by "things that make laravel great for the "notion" of good architecture" ? Are you talking about relationships or usage of Repository ?

Comment: About relationships. Everything in programming is trade-offs and no single pattern or architecture is suited to every case either. If you have a small project, repositories are likely overkill.

Comment: And just to be sure, what do you mean by "small project" ? I have the feeling that my project is big. I have 32 models including 10 that will not be used many times. But for those 22 models left, I have many relationships, many counters that I must be careful to keep up to date to maintain integrity of my data in my database. Repository looks  good for me to avoid repeating things like `findUserByPseudo` but yes, I guess that I could put those kind of methods directly in my Services and it should do the trick.

Comment: There are several things to consider for estimating the "size" of a program, ie) complexity, loc, # of classes etc. etc... If you feel your project warrants repositories, use them! The more experience you get, the better you will be able to feel when certain patterns make sense, and when they do not.

Comment: Eloquent itself does kind of violate the single responsibility principle by allowing you to define relationships within the model. In general Laravel ships with the active record pattern for eloquent (which itself violates the principle) so if you're going for repositories and a strict adherence to the single responsibility principle you need to push what laravel is offering out of your head for a bit and go at it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you both. That really helped me. I think my leak of knowledge about Repository make me trying to strictly follow rules about how it should be used and forget that I'm already using an ORM. I'll try to create an implementation of this pattern that make sense and that meet my needs :)